# Webbrowser on Excel Ribbon?

Tags: vb.net, forms, webbrowser-control, ribbon, excel-addins

I'm using Visual Studio 2008. It is possible to add a Webbrowser item to a Form item, but is it possible to add a Webbrowser item to a Ribbon item ?
Or is there another way of showing a Web Page on the Ribbon ?

There is something called Ribbon-XML, may that do the job ?

Or is it possible to bind a Form (inheriting a Webbrowser) to the Ribbon ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to place any third party controls on the ribbon except the ones defined by the Ribbon scheme.

Instead, you may consider placing a web browser control on a custom task pane. See [Custom Task Panes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942864.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information in MSDN.

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles in MSND:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, I just saw it. I thought about putting the browser on a form which shows when my add-in ribbon tab is activated - thats the reason for the other question i asked. So lets see if the custom task pane does the job..